# Including/Calling another page on jquery tab click?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have below code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css"/>
  ul.tabs {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    height:22px;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:8px 0 -50px 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float:left;
    height:21px;
    line-height:21px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background:#ADD8E6;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    margin:0 2px -1px 0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-size:1em;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    padding:0 20px;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background:#ADD8E6;
}

html ul.tabs li.active,html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
    background:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

.tabContainer {
    border:1px solid #999;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0;
    border-radius:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
}

.labelStyle{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.5em
}

.tabContent {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:20px;
}

.chkAlign{
    margin-left:143px
}


  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

        //hiding tab content except first one
        $(".tabContent").not(":first").hide();
        // adding Active class to first selected tab and show
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 

        // Click event on tab
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            // Removing class of Active tab
            $("ul.tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            // Adding Active class to Clicked tab
            $(this).addClass("active");
            // hiding all the tab contents
            $(".tabContent").hide();       
            // showing the clicked tab's content using fading effect
            $($('a',this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');

            return false;
        });



});

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="tabs">
   <li><a href="#tab1">SEO</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2">Attributes</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab3">Classification SIC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabContainer">
   <div id="tab1" class="tabContent">
    //some static content
   </div>
   <div id="tab2" class="tabContent">
    //some static content
   </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tabContent">
    //here i need to get the page and render 
   </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Now on click of tab3, i have to embed the page

```
http://10.100.12.145:8080/somePage/123
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this;

```
$(/* selector */).on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://10.100.12.145:8080/somePage/123',
        success: function (response) {
            // add response to the container you want: $(/* selector */).html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ashesh, i believe if the page and url page both are on different domains then we will have cross domain restrictions.we cannot access the page..pleasse correct me if am wrong..

Comment: You're right, but that's not really an issue – cross domain issues are avoided for security. The host serving http://10.100.12.145:8080/somePage/123 should also send headers that say that the content returned by it are allowed on the domain requesting the content. Depending on your server, that is quite easy to achieve.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you use a proxy – a script on your server that curls the content requested (from the other domain) and returns them, and you can make ajax calls to your own server sending the url where you want the content from.

Comment: iframes have cross domain limitations also.

Comment: IMHO, the simplest solution is to write a small proxy script.

Comment: This post, http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/, discusses some solutions.